# Possible forms to send something to standard error

Tags: c++, stderr

I'm working with the output of a program to which I have the C++ source code. The program sends output to stderr, and I need to know where/how the output is calculated in the source code.

I know that one form to send something to stderr is

```
std::cerr << "foo";
```

I use grep to see if this form is used, but I can't find it.

I know that is written to stderr because when I run the program I obtain the output in this form:

```
./program 2> file-with-info.txt
```

Are there any other ways for output to be sent to stderr? Can anybody suggest patterns I might grep for to find where this output is being sent?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer for C++ or C#???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not

```
cerr < "foo"
```

but

```
cerr << "foo"
```

You can try to grep for clog (redirected to the standard error stream) too :

```
clog <<
```

You can also search for stderr and perror which are the old C ways to output to standard err

Comment: I try to search with this words: "clog", "cerr" and "stderr" and don't appair too. I find with this command:
     
     `find /Directory-with-source-code/ -exec grep "word" {} \;`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cerr`, `std::clog` and `stderr` all three denote the standard error stream. The first two are the (unbuffered and buffered) C++ interfaces, the third is the old C `stdio` interface. `perror` also writes to standard error.

Depending on the platform, there may be more ways to output to standard error, such as writing to the file descriptor 2 on Unix. (If you're lucky, you can grep for the symbolic constant `STDERR_FILENO`.)

Comment: I try to search with this words: "clog", "cerr", "STDERR" and "stderr" and don't appair too. I find with this command: find /Directory-with-source-code/ -exec grep "word" {} \; 
\n Im working with a machine with Gnu-Linux (Fedora 14)

Comment: @BruceWarrier: `grep -r` is much easier. That said, try grepping for stuff that appears on `stderr` in the source files.

Comment: I try now 
   'grep -r "perror" /Directory-with-source'
and I haven't this word.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable thing to do would be to hook the OS function that writes out and if it's writing to the Standard error output, then break/print callstack. If you settle for anything else, then there's a dozen ways it can be output without you finding that exact string.